# Twilio API for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm using twilio to send messages to what's app I tested it and it's working. I need help for the message to be send every 1hr if the database table of products have products with status 0.

For instance example if there is products with status 0, a message is sent and if they are still products with status 0 after 1hr message is sent until they aren't products.

Thank you

```
//Controller

 public function pendingNotification() {
        $products   = Product::where('status', 0)->get();

        if ($products->any()) {
            $sid    = env('SID'); 
            $token  = env('AUTH_TOKEN'); 
            $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
            $message = $twilio->messages 
                  ->create("whatsapp:+55 555 555", // to 
                           array( 
                               "from" => "whatsapp:+1 555 5555",       
                               "body" => "Hello, you have pending products" 
                           ) 
                  ); 
        print($message->sid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For 1hr repetion thing you can use laravel scheduler or in simple cron job. Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling

Comment: Thanks @somsgod it works like a charm for any who will have trouble adding cron jobs to the cpanel                                                                                           `/usr/local/bin/php /path_to_project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a look at scheduler on the laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling

Your code will look similar to the following:

```
$schedule->command('analytics:report')
         ->hourly()
         ->runInBackground();
```